# fullcalendar v.2 events array with knockout

Tags: knockout.js, fullcalendar

I'm using knockout and I'm pulling events from an observable array. My events appear in console.log but the calendar doesn't render. If I copy the array from console.log and hard code it, the calendar renders fine. What's the difference. How can I troubleshoot this?

```
    viewModel.calendarViewModel = new ko.fullCalendar.cModel({
    events: cModel.events,
    header: {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
    },
    editable: false,
    viewDate: viewModel.viewDate
}, viewModel);
```

snippet from console.log:

```
"calendarViewModel": {
"events": [
  {
    "id": 1304,
    "title": "jjf2017_7_9-10",
    "start": "2017-07-08",
    "end": "2017-07-10",
    "Location": "Guest House",
    "backgroundColor": "Color",
    "RoomNumber": "203"
  },
  {
    "id": 1298,
    "title": "JulyTest",
    "start": "2016-07-09",
    "end": "2016-07-18",
    "Location": "Guest House",
    "backgroundColor": "Color",
    "RoomNumber": "205"
  },
  {
    "id": 1299,
    "title": "Julytest2",
    "start": "2016-07-09",
    "end": "2016-07-14",
    "Location": "Guest House",
    "backgroundColor": "Color",
    "RoomNumber": "209"
  },...
```

Comment: Please try to create a [mcve].

Comment: Here's a fiddle: [link]http://jsfiddle.net/jjfrick/y58wjkkj/ This example works in jsFiddle and my app (if the array is coded) but if I load my data and push it to the array, nothing is displayed, with no errors using Chrome's developer tool. My app is used on our intranet.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a data source that is changing, you might try [using the events property as a function instead of an array](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/events_function/), and then using fullCalendar('refetchEvents') when a change to the data is observed. Here’s a working snippet I have from  a Meteor app.  Whenever the Mongo cursor I am observing changes, I call .fullCalendar(‘refetchEvents’) so that it refreshes the calendar display.  In the example below, I'm grabbing an array of appointments from a Mongo collection, doing a little processing and then using 'callback' which is fullCalendar's way of putting the events on the calendar.  When the data source changes (say, from adding an event via a form), I use fullCalendar('refetchEvents') from my form's success callback to make sure that the changes are rendered. ** you may be able to just use 'refetchEvents' and not mess with using the function structure, but I have not tested that in my case.

```
    events(start, end, timezone, callback) {
  const data = Appointments
    .find()
    .fetch() // <-- here's the array
    // doing some array processing)
    .map(appointment => {
      appointment.editable = ! isPast(appointment.start);
      return appointment;
    });

  if (data) {
    // fullCalendar parses the data and renders it on the cal.
    callback(data);
  }
```